I want to know the redirected URL from current URL
URL = "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/gptfdisk"
I can access this URL in my browser, but it is getting redirected to a newer URL.
Problem: When I give this command to get redirected URL
curl -L http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/gptfdisk -v
Output:
* Connected to downloads.sourceforge.net (204.68.111.105) port 80 (#0)
> GET /sourceforge/gptfdisk HTTP/1.1
> Host: downloads.sourceforge.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.87.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 18 Jun 2024 09:09:58 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 154
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<html>
 <head>
  <title>404 Not Found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
  The resource could not be found.<br /><br />
 </body>

Is there any other command or any script in python that can solve my problem?
Thanks.

Binaries are under https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/files/gptfdisk/1.0.10/gdisk-binaries/ you can use the previous URL (adding the binary you want) with curl ie : curl https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/files/gptfdisk/1.0.10/gdisk-binaries/gdisk-1.0.10-1.x86_64.rpm for RHEL x86_64 binary

It seems that sourceforge is being an ass that the server would decide whether to response with 301 or 404 depending on the User-Agent header. You will see the difference if you copy the UA from your broswer and specify the header with -H. When it's 301 it redirects to https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/files/.
